# Limit text to whole numbers and halves

Tags: asp.net, regex

So I have found how to limit textbox entry to simply numbers using the following:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Only Numbers allowed" ValidationExpression="\d+"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

However, I want to also allow decimals, but only halves (i.e. allow 2.5 and 2, but not 2.3). How could I modify this regex to do this? Or is there another, better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your regex to:

```
\d+(?:\.5)?
```

Comment: So this is almost perfect, however, it does not accept 2.0, which is essentially just 2. I don't know how regex works at all or I'd modify it. I kind of get what's going on (the \d is for digits the and the "?" with the ".5" alows for anything that's ".5" How would I go about this?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it, I changed to "\d+(?:\.5)?(?:\.0)?" Don't know if that's right, but it works.

Comment: @ChristopherBonilla for that you can shorten it a little and you can do: `\d+(?:\.[05])?`. You can use regex101.com that is an excellent tool to test and get regex explained